# The intuition behind the definition of the co-reader monad

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.53.0/docs/Control-Comonad-Reader.html, the co-reader monad is defined, and the co-monadic type modality applies to a type `a` and generates a pair `(r,a)`. The comonadic type modality `w` is therefore of type `a -> (r, a)`.

This is quite different from the reader monad, in which the monadic type modality applies to a type a and generates a function of type `r -> a`, for a particular type `r`.

It is not clear to me why the co-monadic modality is not defined in a way analogous to the reader modality, so that, where `w` is the relevant co-monadic modality, we have  `w a := r -> a`, and then the functions `extract :: w a -> a` and `(<<=) :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b` merely rearrange `return :: a -> m a` and bind `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`, respectively (where `m a : = r -> a`).

This is to say, can the co-reader monad be defined analogously to the reader monad, except that we change the direction of the arrows? Is changing the arrows of bind and of return sufficient to generate (a (?)) co-reader monad? If not, then why not.

Furthermore, would it be possible to define a comonadic modality `w` as  `w a := r -> a`, together with the functions `extract :: w a -> a` and `(<<=) :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b`?

---

Edit: this question has been totally rewritten in response to an objection that it was unclear.

Comment: There is no terminating implementation for the polymorphic type `(e -> a) -> a`, while it's easy to implement `(e, a) -> a` (with `snd`) and its curried variant `a -> ( e -> a)` (with `const`). We can't take the same functor from the monad and make it into a comonad. We need the left adjoint, which is provided by (un)currying.

Comment: This is an interesting subject, but I'm voting to close as unclear for now. If you can make the question precise, please do. — Here's a short discussion on the reader and writer comonads: https://www.olivierverdier.com/posts/2014/12/31/reader-writer-monad-comonad/

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've totally rewritten the question

Comment: @chi What do you mean by a terminating implementation in this context? And why is that important? Why do we need the left adjoint?

Comment: @user65526 Every Haskell type has nonterminating inhabitants, for instance `x :: forall a. a` has the possible implementation `x = x`. That implementation is just sort of an infinite loop that does nothing. These sorts of values are not generally very interesting, so we often ignore them. There are no “interesting” implementations of `x` as a result of the type I’ve given it (“interesting implementations/values” would be terminating values that do not give an exception. The technical term for how I am using “*un*interesting value” here is “bottom”).

Comment: @chi ``(e -> a) -> a`` is a type generated by the continuation monad. But the continuation monad doesn't give rise to problems of the kind you are talking about (or does it?).

Comment: Correct, but for the continuation monad we have `return :: e -> (e -> a) -> a` which is implementable, while `extract :: ((e -> a) -> a) -> e` would be impossible. For the reader monad, we similarly have that `return :: x -> (r -> x)` is implementable, but `extract :: (r -> x) -> x` is not. You can't simply take a monad and turn it into a comonad.

Comment: @chi I suppose, though, that I wasn't talking about monads with respect to Haskell, but monads with respect to the simply typed lambda calculus. In a standard model of the simply typed lambda calculus there is a bijection between the set of individuals of the model and the set of sets to which they belong (i.e, there is a bijection between things of type `e` and things of type `(e -> t) -> t`. So in these models there is a function of type `((e -> t) -> t) -> t`, contrary to what you say is implementable. Maybe I am confusing something here.

Comment: @chi Sorry the should read there is a function of type ``((e -> t) -> t)) -> e`` where type `e` is the type of individuals of a model and type `t` is the type of truth values. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973332/the-existence-of-a-function-between-the-individuals-of-the-domain-and-the-set-of

Comment: If we had an inhabitant of `((e -> False) -> False) -> e` in the STLC then we would have double-negation elimination in intuitionistic logic, thanks to Curry-Howard, making that logic equivalent to classical logic. But that's not the case.

Comment: @chi I think I understand what you mean. The monadic type modality is a modality on intuitionistic types https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296440/modal-collapse-upon-addition-of-the-law-of-the-excluded-middle-to-an-intuitionis?r=SearchResults. However, the logic on the term side of the term : type could actually be classical. It could be the simply typed lambda calculus with a classical semantics in which there is a bijection between things of type `e` and things of type `(e -> t) -> t`.

Comment: But that doesn't mean we can have a constructive monadic modality which maps something of type `(e -> t) -> t` to something of type `e`

Comment: @chi But why is it the case that if you set `w e := r -> e` and `extract` to be of type `(r -> e) -> e` it will not be implementable? I understand why this is the case when `w e := (r -> e) -> e` (it wouldn't be constructive), but I don't understand why in the first case.

Comment: @user65526 Just because in some model a formula is true, it does not mean that it can be proved (it could be false in other models). For the last question: intuitively, if I give you a function `r->e` but no `r`, there's no way for you to construct a `e`. More in general, the proposition `(A->B)->B` isn't an intuitionistic tautology (nor a classical one), so by Curry-Howard it can't be implemented.

Comment: @Chi I think that there has been a confusion. In the simply-typed lambda calculus $(a \to b) \to b$ with the Henkin set-theoretic semantics, there are constants and variables of all types. This is by definition of the language ("Let there be a countably infinite set of constants and variables of each type"). So in the STLC with the Henkin semantics we can always form a term of type $(a \to b) \to b$. There might not be a "terminating implementation" in Haskell, but that seems irrelevant to my question, which was about the STLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comonads and monads are universal constructions, in the sense that, given a monadic type modality `m` and a co-monadic type modality `w`, we must be able to construct `m a` and `w a` and the relevant functions (`return :: a -> m a` and `extract:: wa -> a`and `(>>=)  :: m a -> (  a -> m b) -> m b` and `(<<=) :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b)`, for any type `a`).

The problem is that when `w a:= r -> a`, `extract:: wa -> a` is not universally derivable, for all types `a`. In the simply typed lambda calculus, for example, we cannot find a lambda term of type `wa -> a`, for any type `a` (though in special cases, where `a` is instantiated to a certain type, this may be possible).

Consequently, defining the co-monadic reader modality in this way fails to provide a universal construction of the appropriate type.